# How to run array through compression function

Tags: swift, parse-platform, compression

I would like to have it so that multiple UIImages contained within an array can be compressed and then ran through a compression function however I can not figure out how to get the function to allow for an array of UIImages to be passed through it. Any help would be much appreciated. Here is the function.

```
 func compressForUpload(original:UIImage, withHeightLimit heightLimit:CGFloat, andWidthLimit widthLimit:CGFloat)->UIImage{



    let originalSize = original.size
    var newSize = originalSize

    if originalSize.width > widthLimit && originalSize.width > originalSize.height {

        newSize.width = widthLimit
        newSize.height = originalSize.height*(widthLimit/originalSize.width)

    } else if originalSize.height > heightLimit && originalSize.height > originalSize.width {

        newSize.height = heightLimit
        newSize.width = originalSize.width*(heightLimit/originalSize.height)
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize)
    original.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height))
    let compressedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return compressedImage
}
```

Here is the code that sends the array to the function.

```
let compressedImage = self.compressForUpload(self.selectedImages, withHeightLimit: 720, andWidthLimit: 1080)
                            let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(compressedImage)
                            let imageFile = PFFile(name: "image.png", data: imageData!)

                            post["ImageFile"] = imageFile
```

Comment: How are you imagining it to work for an array? Would the file contain the data for all images combined? Would they all use the same limit numbers? It seems more likely you should be iterating, not passing the array...

Comment: I am imagining that I would initially have the array of UIImages and that I would run it through the compression function to have a new array with the compressed images in it. If their is a better way to do it then I'm definitely open to it as i've never really delt with image compression before.

Comment: Also their will be a limit on how many images will be in the array. The user will be able to pick between 1 - 6 images which are then place into an array. My issue is taking these images and compressing them so that I can send them to parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a wrapper function which takes and returns an array of images. Internally that function uses your existing function inside a loop. It's better to keep the functions logically separate than to mix them together (though that is entirely possible is isn't as reusable).